# How to create a token on the stellar network?

Tags: xlm, token

How does one go about creating tokens on the Stellar network?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's explained in [Issuing Assets](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/issuing-assets.html) article in developer's portal.

The process looks like this:

1. Create an issuing account (let's call it account A)
2. From any other account (let's call it B) create a trust line by sending [`change_trust`](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#change-trust) operation. The [`asset`](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html) value should have the code of the asset you want to issue (ex. `TOKEN`) and issuer should be equal the account A from point 1.
3. Now any [`payment`](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#payment) from A to B sending a custom asset equal to the asset from a trust line from point 2 will create a new asset in the network.

Optionally you can setup another account as the *holding* or *distributor* account and have this account make payments and offers involving the asset.

This way the issuer account can be locked away in cold storage so no more tokens can be created without physical access.

Answer (score 4):

https://stellar.army - see second tab.  The code is also opensourced, see the github link on top right.

Answer (score 4):

I created the following to help understand this.

[image: Activity Diagram of Issuing a Custom Asset on Stellar]

Comment: Hm, i have question. On #8 what do you mean Create and Fund, can u elaborate more.. thanks

Comment: In addition to my question sir, when Distributor send payment operation to Wonderer B, Wonderer C. They will both receive a ROCKT asset. But the Distributor account his/her ROCKT will get decremented or remained as is? thanks.

Comment: @ArmanOrtega sorry missed your comments
#8 create and fund was from a side project and not relevant. It was about sending many accounts some portion of the ROCKT. 

Yes when the Distributor makes a transfer, her account balance will be decremented.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can do this on the commandline using [Lumen](http://github.com/0xfe/lumen). Here's an example to create the `HAK` token on the testnet.

```
# Create accounts for issuer and distributor
$ lumen account new issuer
$ lumen account new distributor

$ lumen friendbot issuer
$ lumen friendbot distributor

# Create a trustline from distributor to the HAK token, issued by issuer.
$ lumen trust create distributor HAK:issuer

# Distribute 1000 HAK tokens
$ lumen pay 1000 HAK:issuer --from issuer --to distributor

# Kill the issuer's account so no more HAK tokens can be created.
$ lumen signer masterweight issuer 0

# The distributor is now free to distribute 1000 HAKs
$ lumen balance distributor HAK:issuer
# Output: 1000.0000000
```

Comment: Using this commandline how does the distributor move the asset HAK to another account ?

Answer (score 0):

1. create accounts from [here](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#account-creator?network=test)
2. fund them from friendbot [here](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#account-creator?network=test)
3. make one account as issuer by issuing asset

var assetName = 'testAsset';
var testAsset = new StellarSdk.Asset(assetName, issuerPublicKey);

4. changeTrust operation.

> //accounts.secret = secretkey of any account other than issuer to get
>   trusted for testAsset
>         var receivingKeys = StellarSdk.Keypair
>               .fromSecret(accounts.secret);
>           server.loadAccount(receivingKeys.publicKey())
>               .then(function (receiver) {
>                   var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(receiver)
>                       // The `changeTrust` operation creates (or alters) a trustline
>                       // The `limit` parameter below is optional
>                       .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.changeTrust({
>                           asset: testAsset,
>                           limit: '1000'
>                       }))
>                       .build();
>                   transaction.sign(receivingKeys);
>                   server.submitTransaction(transaction);

5. do step (4)  for 2 accounts
6. fund these accounts with testAsset using issuer account

> app.get('/transferTestAsset', async function (req, res) {
>       var amt = '100';
>       var sourceSecretKey = issuerSecretKey;    // seed of acc from which tx process
>       var sourcePublicKey = sourceKeypair.publicKey();//pub key of source acc
>       var receiverPublicKey = account5.publicKey;// public key of reciever acc
>       StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork();
>       const account = await server.loadAccount(sourcePublicKey)
>       var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account)
>           .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
>               destination: receiverPublicKey,
>               asset: testAsset,//native asset lumen
>               amount: amt,
>           }))
>           .addMemo(StellarSdk.Memo.text('coins sent testAsset'))//optional 
>           .build();
>       transaction.sign(sourceKeypair);
>       console.log('tx signed');
>       const temp = await server.submitTransaction(transaction)
>       });

7. now do step 6 for accounts other than issuer , accounts which trusted the issuers testAsset can recieve the testAsset
8. go to [here](http://testnet.stellarchain.io/tx/d4fe007dff517b724c402bab959f83f4423b61d2729c973026bd7cf8ab0b54a5)
   and check the transactions