# Can I create a non-fungible token?

Tags: token, assets

I would really love to use a stellar token for a game to track e.g. ownership of different areas/land?

Is this possible with stellar?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. You will have to create a separate [asset](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html) for each item ([kitty](https://www.cryptokitties.co/)/land/area). The key part is that you currently can't change number of decimal places for assets on Stellar which are, by default, divisible to 7 decimal places. If you want your asset to be non-divisible, `0.0000001` of your asset will represent a single item. You will have to present it correctly in your user interface.

## Examples

### Divisible asset (ex. area/land)

If you want to allow your users to send a fraction of unit of your item (up to `1/10,000,000`) you don't have to do anything special in your user interface as they are divisible by default in Stellar. You can create a new issuing [account](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/accounts.html) and send the following assets to your distribution account:

- `1 LAND1`
- `1 LAND2`
- `1 LAND3`

Then you can create a new [offer](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#manage-offer) to sell part of your land like:
`Sell 0.5 LAND1 Buy 1000 XLM`.

### Non-divisible asset (ex. kittens)

Things get a little more complicated for non-divisible assets because you need to update your user interface to interpret `0.0000001` of your asset as a single item. Again, you can create a new issuing [account](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/accounts.html) but this time you only send `0.0000001` of each asset what represents a single item:

- `0.0000001 KITTEN1`
- `0.0000001 KITTEN2`
- `0.0000001 KITTEN3`

Now, because assets on Stellar are divisible only to 7 decimal places you can't send/sell a part of 1 kitten (this would hurt!). So creating a following offer: `Sell 0.0000001 KITTEN1 Buy 1,000 XLM` means you are selling `KITTEN1` for `1,000` XLM.

## Useful links

- [How to create a token on the stellar network?](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/62/how-to-create-a-token-on-the-stellar-network/128#128)
- [Accounts docs](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/accounts.html)
- [Assets docs](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html)
- [Issuing assets guide](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/issuing-assets.html)
- [Distributed exchange](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/exchange.html)

Comment: its a planet as big as our earth.. and tracking each square meter by creating a token for every single square meter seems to be too complicated and will lead to other issues ;)

Comment: @kannix From the code point of view I don't think it complicate things much as it falls under "Non-divisible asset". However there is an obvious scalability issue here. Earth surface area is 510.1 trillion m2. (according to Google). So if you used only 1 byte for each square meter (and it's obviously not enough to store all the ownership info) you'd need 510 TB of storage. I don't any blockchain solution out there can handle this. Even centralised solution for such application isn't trivial.

Comment: @BartekNowotarski do you have a feel for how many `LAND*` assets could be currently supported from a single issuing account in Stellar? I'm concerned about the scalability of things like trustlines and Stellar.toml. For the use-case above, we'd potentially want thousands or millions of LAND Assets.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: right now it's not possible as the way assets are represented is done using trust lines that by design don't distinguish between tokens.

Convoluted answer: you could do it by issuing an asset per unique token (and you would issue only 1 of each). From a data set point of view it's workable (you would use the `ASSET_TYPE_CREDIT_ALPHANUM12` asset type), where this solution breaks down is on usability as transferring tokens would require creating a trust line per token. For somebody to transfer a token to somebody else, the parties would have to cooperate on a multi-sig transaction that does something like:

1. operation1 - create trustline in destination account
2. operation2 - send 1 token to destination
3. operation3 - delete trustline in source account