# Non-fungible tokens?

Tags: token

After exercising due diligence in trying to determine if/to what extent non-fungible tokens (NFTs) are actually feasible on Stellar, this post yielded the most promising hope:

[Can I create a non-fungible token?](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/254/can-i-create-a-non-fungible-token)

> **Non-divisible asset (ex. Kittens)**
>
> Things get a little more complicated for non-divisible assets because you need to update your user interface to interpret 0.0000001 of your asset as a single item. Again, you can create a new issuing account but this time you only send 0.0000001 of each asset what represents a single item:
>
> 0.0000001 KITTEN1
>
> 0.0000001 KITTEN2
>
> 0.0000001 KITTEN3
>
> Now, because assets on Stellar are divisible only to 7 decimal places you can't send/sell a part of 1 kitten (this would hurt!). So creating a following offer: Sell 0.0000001 KITTEN1 Buy 1,000 XLM means you are selling KITTEN1 for 1,000 XLM.

Extrapolating from the above example…

**1)** Instead of only one kitty per token unit, it is possible to move the decimal one place to the left so that there are ten kitties available for each type as follows:

0.0000010 KITTEN1

0.0000010 KITTEN2

0.0000010 KITTEN3

**2)** If so, is it also possible to post the sell offer for a token other than XLM?

For example, is it feasible to create an offer to sell 0.0000001 KITTEN1 for 1,000 MOBI?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to re-assign the decimal for a case use in which limited quantity was the desired effect (vs. single units as above)?

Sure, with 0.0000010 issued, there are only 10 possible divisions, so it could reliably represent 10 distinct entities.

> If so, is it also possible via SDEX/StellarX to post the sell offer for a custom token (instead of XLM)?

StellarX currently only lists tokens that meet certain requirements around volume and use, so it's unlikely a token like this would be able to meet those.

Other UIs like StellarTerm, Stellarport, Interstellar Exchange that list all tokens (or even manually submitting [`manage_offer` transactions](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#manage-offer) to the network) should let you submit offers like you're describing. The Stellar protocol accepts offers between arbitrary assets.